# GIT syncing local feature branch from remote branch

Tags: git, bitbucket, versioning

Maybe got some duplication with other questions, but I couldn't find another post that could answer all my questions

I have a feature branch 'features/abc' which was branch out from another remote branch (in bitbucket) 'releases/car-v2' by

```
In releases/car-v2
git checkout features/abc
```

And then I push this feature branch to remote(in bitbucket) by

```
git push --set-upstream origin features/abc
```

Verified that feature branch already existed in there (in bitbucket)

Now 'releases/car-v2' in remote got some changes, I want to pull these changes to my **local feature branch** 'features/abc' too

Where it is fetching when I use git pull in my local feature branch 'features/abc'?

What should I do to pull the latest changes in remote branch (in bitbucket) 'releases/car-v2' to my local feature branch 'features/abc'?

Comment: I have already answered the very same question. Instead of "main" branch use your "car-v2" branch - https://stackoverflow.com/a/72718825/7357959

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A normal `git pull` is enough, although a `git pull --rebase` is considered better: a `pull --rebase` would replay your local commits on top of the remote ones.

```
git switch features/abc
git pull --rebase
```

Comment: I run git branch -vv --contains HEAD , it shows my head is 'origin/features/abc' (with colorful highlight). 

So, if I run git pull --rebase (after switch statement...), Do i need to explicitly state 'origin releases/car-v2'?

Comment: @JL No because your local branch is already linked to the remote tracking branch `origin/features/abc`. So the pull --rebase should rebase on top of that upstream branch.

Comment: this is something I don't understand, becoz if i use 'git branch -vv --contains HEAD' , it shows many different branches including 'features/abc' and 'releases/car-v2', but starred the 'features/abc'

Comment: @JL Do you see `* 'features/abc     88c5...aSha1 [origin/features/abc]` in the output of `git branch -avv`? If yes, you are good to go.

Comment: does 'you would' refer to what would happen if you do a normal git pull, or if you did a git pull --rebase? The wording is unclear in the answer. Thanks.

Comment: @num Yes, I was referring the `pull --rebase` use case. I have edited the answer accordingly.